# PM2 I/O Unexpected error : Missing mandatory field refresh_token to make a POST request on /api/oauth/token

Tags: node.js, pm2, amazon-linux

When i try to monitor my server with pm2.io, I am getting the error [PM2 I/O] Unexpected error : Missing mandatory field refresh_token to make a POST request on /api/oauth/token

Comment: Same here

```[PM2 I/O] Unexpected error : Missing mandatory field refresh_token to make a POST request on /api/oauth/token```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing has happened to me on an RHEL system (it worked fine a few months ago on another, older RHEL system). I haven't figured it out, but this post has a very simple workaround:

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5253

Basically, login to pm.io from the browser, click `CONNECT`, copy the `pm link` command, and use it instead of `pm login`.

Comment: pm link does not work as well for me...